# how do i share an image on facebook?

Tags: facebook, image, share, facebook-opengraph

I read about that I have to include this in my head tag

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $photo['photo_name']; ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $photo['description']; ?>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $url; ?>detail.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $canvas_url. 'libs/upload/upload/' .$photo['user_id'] .'/miniatury/' .$photo['name']; ?>" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="<?php echo $canvas_url. 'libs/upload/upload/' .$photo['user_id'] .'/miniatury/' .$photo['name']; ?>" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="<?php echo $appId; ?>
```

the php script is correct , but still i don't get anything when i share an image. I got this : [image]
how can i manage that ?  thx

Answer (score 0):

You want to publish a feed, where you want to show an image too right?

Define `og:picture` tag. Eg:

```
<meta property="og:picture" ....>
```